# Discord.js Meme Generator code not working

Tags: discord.js

Can Anyone Tell Why My Meme Generator Code is Not Working?
So I'm making a meme generator in discord.js that generates random memes when someone says "gg!meme"

```
client.on('message', message => {
    module.exports = {
        name: "meme",
        category: "fun",
        description: "Sends an epic meme",
        run: async (client, message, args) => {
            // In this array, 
            // you can put the subreddits you want to grab memes from
            const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
            // Grab a random property from the array
            const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];
    if (message.content === 'gg!meme') {
                // Get a random image from the subreddit page
                const img = await randomPuppy(random);
                const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor("RANDOM")
                    .setImage(img)
                    .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
                    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

                message.channel.send(embed);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview:** Yeah I know why. It looks like you've completely copied and pasted a source of code and put it in your code without understanding what its doing.

**Issue:** You have inputted a command handler structured command inside a non-command handler script.

**Issue: #2** This code is outdated and seems to be Discord.js v11

Assuming your script is ran without a command handler, this should work:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'gg!meme') {
         // In this array, 
            // you can put the subreddits you want to grab memes from
            const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
            // Grab a random property from the array
            const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];
                // Get a random image from the subreddit page
                const img = await randomPuppy(random);
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("RANDOM")
                    .setImage(img)
                    .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
                    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

                message.channel.send(embed);
            }
});
```

**Suggestion:**

*Instead of typing `gg!` every time you make a command, why don't you turn it into a variable you can always refer to.*

```
Example:
const prefix = 'gg!'

Usage:
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ping')) {
 return message.channel.send('pong!')
}
```

*Assuming you also have the npm package `randompuppy` installed this should work.*

Comment: There is a Problem at const img = await randomPuppy(random); Something is wrong with "await"

Comment: remove the `await` function, sorry for not noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated version of discord.js.

Install the latest version of discord.js by typing `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal. In the latest version `RichEmbed` got replaced with `MessageEmbed`.

Comment: To be honest i removed that code but it still works so thanks